# Change font inside Thunderbird 68.7.0 64 bit

Tags: fonts, thunderbird

I am using 18.04 and Thunderbird 68.7.0 64-bit. I am ok with other default settings but font. I would like to change it to Raleway, if possible. I tried through `Preferences`(screenshot below) without success. Whatever I enter, I get the same default font in Thunderbird. I would at least like to have the listing fonts changed to Raleway - 24. It is ok even if the messages ( inside ) are of a different font. Any help will be great.

[image]

Update :

Looks like the font changes inside the email (content) but not in listing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This window lets you change only the fonts in emails, not those in the Thunderbird app itself.

There used to be an Add-on for this (Theme Font & Size Changer for ThunderBird) but it doesn't work with current versions of Thunderbird. Luckily, it isn't very difficult to change these things manually.

1. Locate your profile folder. It is called `[random string].default` and it's located in `/home/[username]/.thunderbird`.
2. In it, find the `chrome`folder. If there is none, create one. (This has nothing to do with the Google browser of the same name BTW.)
3. In it, open the file `userChrome.css` with your favourite text editor. Again, if you don't have one, create one.
4. This is standard CSS. To change the font everywhere, enter:

   ```
   * {
       font-family: 'Raleway', Arial, sans-serif;
   }
   ```
5. Save the file, restart Thunderbird, and see your changes.

Comment: Did everything you mentioned, but Thunderbird still uses the default font. I had to create the folder and file. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Your `userChrome.css` file seems to be not picked up. Are you in the right profile directory? Did you enter syntactically correct CSS? (I edited my answer to show the proper indentation for clarity.) Does `* { border: 1px solid purple;}` work? (That one is noticable, believe me.)

Comment: It was due to the wrong folder. I used random.default. It worked when I used random.default-release. Many thanks :)